# Why download URL works when pasted/entered in browser address bar but not in a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I want to download Rar file from another server.

If I use a tag I can not download file and I redirect from parent server.

For example if I paste this [download link](http://s1.mihandownload.com/2012/Feisal/October/Tipard_Total_Media_Converter_v6.1.38_www.MihanDownload.com.rar) url into address bar and press enter the download start but if I add this to a tag and click on it the download doesn't start.

Comment: Is that a warez site? Anyways, your problem may be referrals

Comment: No it is not warez site.it is a site how share file

Comment: But the link apparently points to a full version of software which seems to be shareware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click a link that leads you to a different website, your browser sends information to that website about the site you clicked the link from. This is called the [referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), a field present in your request to the server.

Servers can check for a referer and change the behavior to their response. This is one of the ways used to disable hotlinking images. You might have seen how, if you try to link and image from another website, you sometimes can't get the image to appear on the page you want and it is often substituted.

The reason it works when you paste it in your address bar is that when you navigate to an URL this way, there is no referer information sent, so the server may respond differently. In your case, that seems to mean that they'll give you access to the file!

I hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer.it server share the file.is it any way to slove this problem?

Comment: You'd have to set your browser up not to send referer information. You can't fix it so you can 'hotlink' from your page to another without that information being sent by other people, I believe. You can make the request go through a service like anonym.to, but that's just going to hide the original referer, not strip it altogether.